# How to combine jquery date-picker and jquery full calendar

Tags: jquery-ui, fullcalendar

Can any one tell me how I could update a selection in a date picker to a full calendar ie When user selects date from DatePicker then FullCalendar loads events for given date.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at this : **[Issue 167: Mini Calender to control Main Calender](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=167&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars)**.

Or make the combination with following example :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fullcalendar").fullCalendar({
        // .....
    });

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var d = new Date(dateText);
            $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', d);
        }
    }); 
}
```

```
<div id="fullcalendar"></div>
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Comment: Would this also work for bootstrap-datepicker? it should, right? i'm using 'changeDate' event https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html with your solution trying to update the end date of my event, but nothing happen at all... Any idea also how to debug `gotoDate` ? What should be the behaviour?

Comment: With a non-english datepicker this won't work, use var d = new Date(inst.currentYear, inst.currentMonth, inst.currentDay);

Comment: for bootstrap-datepicker add .on('changeDate', function (ev) {
            $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', ev.date); });

Answer (score 2):

The "gotoDate (method)" would help you select a date programatically in fullcalendar. So let the user select a date using jquery date picker and register a onchange event on the text input that captures the date. When the onchange fires, use gotoDate to set the date in fullcalendar. Refer - http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date

Answer (score 1):

This might help anyone coming to this answer to add a gotoDate datepicker to fullcalendar as a custom button

```
customButtons: {
    gotoDate: {
        text: 'Go to date',
        click: function () {
            $(this).datepicker({
                autoclose: true
            });
            $(this).datepicker().on('changeDate', function (e) {
                $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', e.date);
            });
            $(this).datepicker('show');
        }
    },
},
footer: {
    'center': 'gotoDate'
},
```