# Fullcalendar combined with bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm try to update fullcalendar event after user change date from bootstrap-datepicker: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html

I'm following the (only) solution found here: [How to combine jquery date-picker and jquery full calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878898/how-to-combine-jquery-date-picker-and-jquery-full-calendar)

which for bootstrap-datepicker would be:

```
$('#fullcalEventEnd').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(evt){
                var endDate = evt.date;

                list.eventUpdated.end = moment(endDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
                $(cal).fullCalendar('renderEvent', list.eventUpdated, true);
    });
```

What it should do is, update an event created once the user selects the calendar, so on my select function i have:

```
  select: function(start, end) {

            $('#fullcalEventFrom').datepicker('setValue', start);
            $('#fullcalEventTo').datepicker('setValue', end);

            list.eventUpdated = {
                title: eventTitle,
                start: start,
                end: end
            };

            $(cal).fullCalendar('renderEvent', list.eventUpdated, true); // stick? = true
            $(cal).fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
        }, 
        ....
```

`list` is my global object: `var list = {}`

But so far nothing, I'm not able to update the event and this line
`$(cal).fullCalendar('renderEvent', list.eventUpdated, true);` is giving me an error and I don't understand why

Anyone already face this problem?

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: `Cannot set property 'end' of undefined` It would be great if i could put the datepicker code into the select function. But doing so the evt on changeDate  will be different and it will not work anymore..